# Convert List<V> into new object V using Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8

I have list of objects of Class V and I want to create a new object of same class V. Some properties of objects in List are same across the list and some properties have different values. I want to create new object V having commons properties as they are and properties with different values should be summed up and set into object V.

For example,

```
Class Sample {
    Integer someId; // which is not unique
    String someString; // Not unique
    Date date;
    BigDecimal value;
}
```

I have List as follows.

```
Sample s1 = new Sample(1, "1", 20151231, 10.10);
Sample s2 = new Sample(1, "1", 20151231, 20.10);
```

I want new Sample object with values as

```
new Sample(1, "1", 20151231, 10.10 + 20.10);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: More information is needed.  Are you assuming certain properties have common values, or are you analyzing the list to determine which properties have common values?  What if not all objects in the List have the same value for the common properties?

Comment: What do you want to group your samples by? The id? The String? The Date? All 3 of them?

Comment: So what if `someString` or `date` differ? You want them all to be summed up?

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Sample s1 = new Sample(1, "1", Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), new BigDecimal(10.10));
    Sample s2 = new Sample(1, "1", Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), new BigDecimal(20.20));

    List<Sample> samples = new ArrayList<>();
    samples.add(s1);
    samples.add(s2);



    Optional<Sample> result = samples.stream().reduce((sa1,sa2)->new Sample(1, "1", Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),sa1.getValue().add(sa2.getValue())));
    System.out.println(result.get());
}
```